# How to make my player stick to platform when the collide and unstick when jump button is clicked?

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a game where player jump to the platform and stick and when jump button is pressed it jumps again. please help me .Thank you

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have made an environment with some platforms and a player game object which jumps from one platform to another ..and I want the player game object to stick to the platform when it land on it and when jump button presser it should unstick itself and jump from that platform to another

Comment: So basically I want to know anyways by which two colliders or rigid bodies stick together upon collision as if there was glue on their surfaces and  unstick itself and jump input is given

Comment: This looks like a problem you can solve by [searching for "unity moving platform"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+moving+platform&ia=web)  and following any of the dozens of guides that have already been written, without waiting for users here to write something new for you.

Comment: thanks...Thank You very much. for your response . i get that working by applying freezing constraints when touching the specific platform

Comment: Depending how your platforms and characters are set up you can try 
parenting upon landing and make non-parented when jumping/falling of moving platform - i.e. de-parent if not grounded and becomes child when grounded and ground is of moving type.

Comment: sorry For the late reply! i got it working and Thank you very much for your reply